# Django model foreign key in the same table

Tags: django

Before to send this kind of modification to my database, I just would like to know if what I do is OK or not.

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path_comments, validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True)
    articles = models.ForeignKey(Articles, verbose_name="Article", null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Auteur")
    in_answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Comments, verbose_name="En réponse au commentaire", blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I have a model called Comments for listing the comments in my article's blog. I want to add the functionality to answer to a comment and so I add a field name where, if it's an answer, I add the ID of the comment.

So, is it OK if I add a foreign key field, knowing that it's is about the same table ? This is not really a foreign key ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have a `ForeignKey` that references the same model, but in that case you should use `'self'` as the `othermodel` argument.

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.